# Get each chekbox group values into separate variables upon form submission

Tags: php

I have multiple checkbox groups, and once the form is submitted, I want each group of checkboxes that were selected to be added to their own variable.

This is the form:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<p>apple <input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="fruits[]" /></p>
<p>orange <input type="checkbox" value="orange" name="fruits[]" /></p>
<p>peach <input type="checkbox" value="peach" name="fruits[]" /></p>

<br>

<p>red <input type="checkbox" value="red" name="colors[]" /></p>
<p>green <input type="checkbox" value="green" name="colors[]" /></p>
<p>blue <input type="checkbox" value="blue" name="colors[]" /></p>

<br>

<p>chicken <input type="checkbox" value="chicken" name="meats[]" /></p>
<p>pork <input type="checkbox" value="pork" name="meats[]" /></p>
<p>lamb <input type="checkbox" value="lamb" name="meats[]" /></p>

<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my code:

```
$string = 'fruits,colors,meats';
$str_array = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($str_array as $value) {
    if (isset($_GET[$value])) {
        $group_name = $_GET[$value];

        foreach ($group_name as $group_item) {
            $group_string .= ' ' . $group_item;
        }
    }


}

echo $group_string;
```

With that code, if I choose for example the first checkbox in each group and hit `submit`, I will get the following value of `$group_string` = `apple red chicken` in one string.

What I get **does make sense to me** as per the code I wrote, but what I want is for each option group to have its own variable to which its values are asigned, so what I want is to get is the following (assuming I again chose the first option from each group):

```
$fruits = 'apple'; 
$colors = 'red';
$meats = 'chicken';
```

But I don't know how to rewrite it so I get that. Also, the number of options groups is not known upfront, it has to happen dynamically.

Comment: I think you have to set `$group_string` to an empty string at the beginning of the foreach-loop, otherwise the values of the previous group are echoed again!

Comment: But then I will again have just one variable, `$group_string`, for all groups won't I?

Comment: if you want to create a dynamic number of variables with dnyamic names, using `eval` is the way I would go: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: What would be perfect if they could have the names that checkboxes have, like I wrote at the end - what I wanted to achieve. the last part of code in my q.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm: What's wrong with simply `implode()`ing from the $_GET variables? Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I took the liberty of rewriting part of your php for my convenience but here it is

#### your new *and improved* php file

```
<?php
// assume we know beforehand what we are looking for
$groups = explode(',','fruits,colors,meats');
foreach ($groups as $group) {
  if (isset($_GET[$group])) {
    $vv = array();
    foreach ($_GET[$group] as $item) $vv[] = $item;
    $$group = implode(' ',$vv);
  }
}
var_dump($fruits,$colors,$meats);
?>
```

I used a construct in PHP called `variable variables`. This is actually an almost ***identical*** answer as the one @Lohardt gave. I hope this can help you out. If it doesn't then post me a comment

Comment: When I run this I get `NULL` regardless of which option I choose. Did you actually test this out with the `html` I have in the Q?

Comment: holy cow!!!! I totally f**** this one up... sorry, I'll get back to you as soon as I fix it T_T

Comment: ok, fixed now... wow, I must have had some brain derps going on back there. It should be vardumping it and I tested it this time ^^

Comment: This is great! I wish I had seen this yesterday because I spent hours doing a workaround, but I'll keep this for future reference. No way I could've come up with this myself.

Comment: glad I could help. BTW take a good luck at php's [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Although I do not recomend this sort of thing, it's only useful in a handfull of cases

Comment: Yea, but you never know what you can end up needing. I needed exactly this yesterday. I'll be sure to study this code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="groups[fruits][]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="groups[colors][]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="apple" name="groups[meats][]" />
```

Your $_POST will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [fruits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => apple
                )

            [colors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                )

        )

)
```

And it should be simple to use a foreach loop to get the keys and values.

Edit: then you can assign the value to variables like this:

```
${$key} = $value;
```

and use it you would do any variable:

```
echo $color;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how that relates to the question. Have you even read it whole?

Comment: Not really, he's already using a foreach loop, his problem is that all the values go to one variable, your code examples and explanations don't really help solving his problem.

Comment: ${$key} = $value; does what he wants. He will end up with a $fruits, $color and $meats with the values in them.

Comment: `$key` of what? `$value` of what? If applied to OP's example, `$key` doesn't exist, and `$value` holds what you call the `$key`.

Comment: $key => $value as in 'color' => 'red' via an foreach

Comment: OK, my bad, this is not what he wants

Comment: My bad again! this is very close to what _I think he wants_ (I dunno)